# I need to sum numbers from a file

Tags: python

I'm reading numbers from a text file whose structure is two numbers per line. I need to open this file, and sum the numbers from the range of the two. My program does exactly as I want it to except when it gets to negative ranges. Because I need to add all the numbers, I added a + 1 to the end of the maxNumber for the range. However, this is where if the maxNum is negative four for example, it makes the range go from -3 instead of -5 as it should. How can I fix this? I also am wondering the best way to write the results to the outPut file. Thanks

```
def numberSum1():
inFile = input('Please enter name of input file: ')
outFile = input('Please enter name of output file: ')

with open(inFile, 'r') as file1, open(outFile, 'w') as file2:
    finalList = []
    x = file1.readline()



    for x in file1:
        n, m = x.split()
        print(n,m)
        minNum = int(min(n,m))
        maxNum = int(max(n,m))
        print(minNum)
        print(maxNum)
        for w in range(minNum, maxNum + 1):
            finalList.append(w)

            finalContent = sum(finalList)
        print('Sum from {} to {} is {}'.format(minNum, maxNum, finalContent))
        finalList = []


file1.close()
file2.close()
```

Comment: Could you describe the 'it makes the range go from -3 instead of -5 as it should'? I don't fully understand what you mean by that.

Comment: As you know for the range function, it goes from the first parameter, to one plus the second parameter. Say the range for numbers to be summed is from -2 to -4. well when trying to add those in my equation, it goes from -2 to -3 because of the +1 added for the nested for loop.

Comment: So what you said at the end, to confirm, is that what's going WRONG, or is it what should be happening? And whichever it is, what should/is happening? I just want to make sure I'm understanding the problem.

Comment: Do you have negative numbers in your file?

Comment: Yes I have negative numbers in my file and the goal of the program is to print out this for each line in the file. For Example, the line in the file contains -2 -4. So, my program adds -2 + -3 + -4 and should return "Sum from -2 to -4 is -9. But my program returns the sum as these two numbers to be 0. @Vikram

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the parameters that you pass to your `min` and `max` functions. You need to convert them from `strings` to `ints` BEFORE you compare them to see which is bigger (right now, it's incorrectly thinking that `"-4"` is bigger than `"-2"`). Try this instead:

```
for x in file1:
    n, m = [int(k) for k in x.split()]
    minNum = min(n,m)
    maxNum = max(n,m)
```

Comment: Perfect that did the trick thanks @Adriano ! What's the best way to get these results into my outFile?

Comment: Instead of printing them to the console, write it to a file by doing something like: `file2.write('Sum from {} to {} is {}.\n'.format(minNum, maxNum, finalContent))`

Comment: Anyway to do both? @Adriano

Comment: Sure, you could just leave the `print` statement there and add the extra line of code after it.